# Chrome undocumented keyboard shortcuts for images and links

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Chrome's list of [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en) don't list any that work with the right click menu. (I.e. when you right click, then press a key to do something.)

But there is at least one undocumented shortcut: if you right click an image, then press V, it will download the image.

Are there others, and they are simply undocumented, like pressing V? I'm talking specifically about images and links.

For example, Firefox has many of these kinds of shortcuts, indicated by underlining the letter to press:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all menus, in nearly all Windows applications, have these shortcuts. Often they aren't indicated until you use the keyboard to actually open the menu, however.

Press either the <kbd>≣</kbd> [Menu key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to open the context menu for the selected item, and all shortcuts should become visible.

Comment: I should have been more specific. It's images and links where the options don't appear. If you just click somewhere else on a webpage, yes, it will show you some keyboard options.

Comment: I am not talking about the right-side "dedicated" keyboard shortcuts. Open any menu on Windows (e.g. using Alt), you'll see underlined letters in every menu item. Chrome used to have that too, unfortunately I just now noticed that it no longer shows those underlines no matter how the menu is opened.